# AngularJS - Refresh partial views

Tags: angularjs, partial-views

I have a single page app made up of partial views. I'd like to refresh the partial views on click of an element without reloading the page. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Could you give us an example of code ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the comment by Aliz below your answer would be the question everyone is asking, but i'll try answer your question assuming the example code below is analogous to what you're trying to archive.

```
<section controller='ctrl'>
   <span>{{ text }}</span>
   <button ng-click="update()">update text</button
</section>





angular.module('myApp')
.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout){
   // the data inside $scope.text can be dynamically populated from an AJAX call result. (doesn't matter where its from)
   $scope.text = 'hello world!';

   $scope.update = function() {
      // sometimes this doesn't work and you need to call $scope.$apply below to forcefully update the view.
      $scope.text = 'new text';

      $timeout(function(){
         $scope.$apply();
      }, 0);
   }
}];
```

If this isn't what you're trying to archive then post your code for further help.

Comment: why the $timeout? can you help?